# Add user role with ValidUntil DateTime .NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, roles, membership-provider

I extend UsersInRoles table with ValidUntil datetime field.

[image: Table Design]

Now i want to use use .net membership AddUserToRole function, but i cant pass validuntil.

i try to override but i cannot use LinqToSql UserInRoles class.. so since i have expirience only with LinqToSql i want some help how to execute sql query;

I want to use my custom function like

```
 public bool AddUserToRole(Guid UserID, string RoleName, DateTime? ValidUntil)
 {
       Guid RoleID = StaticValue.GetRoleID(RoleName); 
       // add new UserID = UserID, RoleId = RoleID, ValidUntil = ValidUntil

 }
```

[image: Add User In Role]

Comment: like this one :). I am willing to help but SO rules requires your effort. how is it going?

Comment: it np, i think someone have some better solution, but if only pure sql query is needed, its easy to learn since is basic insert :)

Comment: the way you frame your question determines what response you get. From your question, it indicates you only want to execute sql query

Comment: Please accept the best answers although they aren't exactly what you are looking for. It'll help the community. Besides, it is just a way of saying 'Thanks' to those who take their time to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Roles.AddUserToRole`, it calls this function

```
static public void AddUserToRole(string username, string roleName){
   ...
   Provider.AddUsersToRoles(new string [] {username}, new string [] {roleName}); 
   ... 
}
```

`Provider.AddUsersToRoles` from above function calls `RoleProvider`'s AddUsersToRoles

```
public abstract void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames);
```

The bottom line is you cannot call custom functions created inside a custom role provider like Roles.AddUserToRole(-, -, -)

Instead, you have to create your own Role service/manager class, and insert/update/delete to UsersInRoles table by yourself.